# jQuery append html loading randomly on page reresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullpage.js

I have a this problem:

I use a jquery [plugin fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) by Alvaro Trigo on my website. The plugin script automatically inserts the html structure in certain elements... in my html I have:

```
<div class="section fp-auto-height-responsive" id="slider-section">
    <div class="slide" id="co-delame-section">
      <div class="slide-wrapper">
        ...
      </div>     
    </div>
  </div>
```

And when the page is loading, javascript generates extra html tags and css, so it looks like:

```html
<div class="section fp-auto-height-responsive fp-section active fp-completely" id="slider-section" data-anchor="About" style="height: 638px;">    
  <div class="fp-slides">
    <div class="fp-slidesContainer" style="width: 100%;">
      <div class="slide fp-slide fp-table active" id="co-delame-section" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="fp-tableCell" style="height:638px;">      
          <div class="slide-wrapper">      
          </div>          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>              
</div>
```

I want to append more slides (slide class) for a certain page resolution, so that when user is on mobile with smaller screen, the extra slides won't load.

I do it with this javascript code:

```js
$.get("http://marketingo.cz/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/slider_cs.html", function (data) {
    $("#slider-section").append(data);
  });
```

And there is the problem... it works in about 50% page loads, the problem is that sometimes it appends the slides after the fullPage generates the structure, so that the appended slides are out of the slider structure... like this:

```html
<div class="section fp-auto-height-responsive fp-section active fp-completely" id="slider-section" data-anchor="About" style="height: 638px;">    
  <div class="fp-slides">
    <div class="fp-slidesContainer" style="width: 100%;">
      <!-- the right place of a slide -->
      <div class="slide fp-slide fp-table active" id="co-delame-section" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="fp-tableCell" style="height:638px;">      
          <div class="slide-wrapper">      
          </div>          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <!-- appended slides out of slider blocks --> 
  <div class="slide" id="jsme-partner">                        
  </div>                                     
  <div class="slide" id="vase-problemy">                                
  </div>
</div>
```

So it looks the fullPage.js script runs before the slides are appended, but in the html head tag I firstly put the script to append the slides and fullPage is loaded after...

But what is really weird is that sometimes it loads correctly, sometimes not. Clearing the cache on refresh helps sometimes, but I can't say if there is any pattern with deleting the cache.

You can check it on http://marketingo.cz/en/?stack-overflow#About and give it a few refreshes with cache clearing to see...

**The questions is - how can I ensure that the html is appended before the fullPage plugin modifies the code so that the appended sliders will be in a same container?**

Thanks for a help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy.

Just initialice fullPage.js after you append the slides by using the `$.get` callback.

```
$.get("http://marketingo.cz/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/slider_cs.html", function (data) {
    $("#slider-section").append(data);

    //initialice fullPage.js here:
    $('#fullpage').fullpage();
});
```